# Mismatched Radios: A Baofeng UV-5R & a Cobra ACXT 645

Tags: united-states, baofeng

I've got a Baofeng UV-5R and a [Cobra ACXT 645](https://www.cobrafrs.com/products/acxt645), and I'm trying to get them to communicate.

The Cobra transmits and the Baofeng (programmed with CHIRP) receives, but not the other way around.

I've tried different channels, different frequencies, and with the CTCSS and DCS on and off. I'm on day 3 now and have begun pulling my hair out.

- What am I doing (or not doing) wrong here?
- Why aren't the radios working like they're supposed to?

I'm a beginner at all this.

Comment: The Cobra thing is a [GMRS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Mobile_Radio_Service) device, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added a link to his post. The domain "cobra**frs**.com" *may* imply that it's an [FRS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Radio_Service) radio. But I know what you're thinking, I can read your mind. ;-)

Comment: Hello Mike, and welcome to the site! In what country are you planning on using those radios? That can affect some legal issues with using the Baofeng on non-amateur frequencies.

Comment: The Cobra may be [desensing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desensitization_(telecommunications)) due to too high a signal level at the antenna. Try it with the radios farther apart.

Comment: I'm in the US and have these radios for a very specific reason - should things get... sticky... I want to be able to communicate with family members. I understand the legal ramifications and have no intention on doing any broadcasting other then to make sure they work. I have 3 other Baofengs but the Cobra was a gift and I'd like to incorporate it into the lot.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's illegal in the US for the UV-5R to transmit on FRS/GMRS frequencies except in specific types of emergencies.  Even testing the ability is illegal.

Comment: @MikeEhrmantraut If you knew it was illegal, you shouldn't have wasted your time asking for help.  There aren't many people here who would willingly help you break the law.